# VS CODE - disable UNDO command after file was closed

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I'm making some files changes then close it and then reopen it, I will be able to undo those changes. How can I disable this behaviour that only changes made in the current open session can be reverted?

PS: this behaviour was not present for older versions of VS code.

Comment: Open issue - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94778

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [v1.45 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#disable-persistent-undo):

> **Disable persistent Undo**
>
> Last milestone, changed the Undo/Redo stack to be persisted when you
>   close a file and reopen it. Not everyone wanted this new feature, so
>   there is now a setting, `files.restoreUndoStack`, to disable
>   persistent Undo.

[Additional info: see [v1.46 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#cross-file-undo-in-closed-files) - you can undo even in files that were closed and remain closed.]

Comment: I have v1.44 but no updates pending. what's going wrong?

Comment: V1.45 will be out later this week.  It is in the Insiders' Build already.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using the following steps:

1. Open **Setting**
2. Type **undo** in the search box
3. Uncheck the checkbox of **Restore Undo Stack**

> You can follow the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

- Open VS code
- Click on manage {bottom-left}
- Click settings
- Search undo
- Uncheck restore undo stack